# Displaying a div over the top of an img

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a relatively simple HTML layout where a div is meant to be displayed over the top of an img.

But what actually happens is that the div gets displayed below the image. Do you know how I can get the div with the id 'main' to be displayed over the top of the img with the id 'mainImg' (but the div also needs to be/remain centred).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Kamalei - Home Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        html, body, div, form, fieldset, legend, label, img {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  }  table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0; }  th, td {  text-align: left;  }  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, th, td, caption { font-weight:normal; }  img { border: 0; } 

        #mainImg  { z-index: -1; }
        #main     { text-align: center; width: 1000px; height: 700px; top: 0px; }
        #navBar   { float: left; width: 200px; height: 700px; /*margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 20%; padding: 30px; width: 20%;*/ }
        #content  { float: left; width: 800px; height: 700px; /*margin-right: 10%; margin-top: 20%; padding: 30px; width: 80%;*/ }
    -->
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="heading"> 
        <img src="images/heading.png" alt="" width="100%" height="300px"/>
    </div>

    <img id="mainImg" src="images/mainBackground.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"/>

    <!-- the below div is meant to be displayed over the top of the above image but it actually get display below it -->
    <div id="main">
        <div id="navBar">
            <img src="images/navBackground.png" alt="" width="100%" height="700px"/>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <img src="images/contentBackground.png" alt="" width="100%" height="700px"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use the css property `position: absolute` for your div and then tamper with margins of the div to position it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an img tag for your site's background I would strongly suggest applying a background image style to a div or your body tag. 
That way you can keep a floated layout & the contents will appear above the image since your #main div can be nested inside the element with the backgrund image applied.

so for example css would be:

```
body { background:url('images/mainBackground.png'); }
```

and just remove the img (#mainImg) tag from your markup

you may also want to do this for your navigation

Comment: And what about when the image doesn't resize to fit different sized screens, the MAJOR limitation of CSS

Comment: So you want this image to resize based on the user's screen size? You could always use media queries instead, which you can use to change the image used depending on the user's resolution

Comment: here is an article about media queries : http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ using the browser to resize an image based on the user's window size will probably make the image very pixelated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing the image as an inline  tag, try setting the CSS background properties of the content div itself.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
#main {
background-image:url('images/mainBackground.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#mainImg {
    left: 100px;/*adjust accordingly*/
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;/*adjust accordingly*/
    z-index: 2;
}
```

z-index is for layering html elements.